# Image not staying within my div

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to keep the image inside my div element. The image is stretching outside of it.
I cannot seem to find the source of the error and have researched a lot, and still cannot find the source. Some help would be awesome!

Here is my HTML/CSS...

```css
.navigation {
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
}
.container {
 
 
}

.brand-text {
 font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: 700px;
 color: black;
 -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
 text-align: center;
 
}

.brand-text:hover {
 color: grey;
 
}
.nav-brand {
 text-decoration:none;
}

.nav-menu {
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-link {
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
 -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
 position: relative;
}

.nav-link:hover {
 color: grey;
}

/*Gallery*/

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 
}

div.img {
 margin: 5px;
 float: left;
 width: 180px;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease, box-shadow 400ms ease;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease, box-shadow 400ms ease;
 background-color: #fff;
}

div.img:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
 box-shadow: 0 0 50px -14px #000;
 opacity: 0.8;
 
}

div.img img {
 width: 100%
 height: auto;
}

div.desc {
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 padding: 15px;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
 .reponsive {
  width: 49.999999%;
  margin: 6px;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
 .responsive {
  width: 100%
 }

}

.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Josh Corbett</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navigation">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="nav-brand" href="#"><h1 class="brand-text">Josh Corbett</h1></a>
   <nav class="nav-menu" role="navigation">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="#">
   <img src="http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-1-1024x640.png" alt="Mountain" width="300" height="200">
   <div class="desc">Beautiful Montain</div>
  </a>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Closing as typo error, you miss a semicolon after `div.img img {
 width: 100%`

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I never noticed that.

Comment: np mate glad to help. next time first ensure with the inspector tools if the css is correct

Answer (score 0):

try

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

this will keep ur img inside its container

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot the `;` in your `div.img img` definition :

```
div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```css
.navigation {
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
}
.container {
 
 
}

.brand-text {
 font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: 700px;
 color: black;
 -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
 text-align: center;
 
}

.brand-text:hover {
 color: grey;
 
}
.nav-brand {
 text-decoration:none;
}

.nav-menu {
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-link {
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
 -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
 position: relative;
}

.nav-link:hover {
 color: grey;
}

/*Gallery*/

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 
}

div.img {
 margin: 5px;
 float: left;
 width: 180px;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease, box-shadow 400ms ease;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease, box-shadow 400ms ease;
 background-color: #fff;
}

div.img:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
 box-shadow: 0 0 50px -14px #000;
 opacity: 0.8;
 
}

div.img img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

div.desc {
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 padding: 15px;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
 .reponsive {
  width: 49.999999%;
  margin: 6px;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
 .responsive {
  width: 100%
 }

}

.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Josh Corbett</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navigation">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="nav-brand" href="#"><h1 class="brand-text">Josh Corbett</h1></a>
   <nav class="nav-menu" role="navigation">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="#">
   <img src="http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-1-1024x640.png" alt="Mountain" width="300" height="200">
   <div class="desc">Beautiful Montain</div>
  </a>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are explicitly setting the image width and heigth to width="300" height="200"

So since you already specify the image width on your CSS.
Change this:

```
<img src="http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-1-1024x640.png" alt="Mountain" width="300" height="200">
```

To this

```
<img src="http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-1-1024x640.png" alt="Mountain">
```

(remove width and height attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ; at end of the image width propery.

```
div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what your looking for but you can try to change the picture elements size properties to 100%.

So change this line:

```
<img src="http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-1-1024x640.png" alt="Mountain" width="300" height="200">
```

To this:

```
<img src="http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-1-1024x640.png" alt="Mountain" width="100%" height="100%">
```